# Implementation of Kullback–Leibler divergence in Mathematica: dealing with negative infinity?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, built-in-symbols

I'm trying to implement a function to calculate Kullback-Liebler Divergence  but I am running into a problem with complex infinities in my intermediate result.  Here is how I have implemented it thus far:

```
pmfA={1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6};
pmfB={1/4,1/4,1/8,1/8,1/8,1/8};

Function[{p, q}, p*Log[p] /Log[q]][pmfA,pmfB]
Total[%]
```

For some "nice" sample data (containing no zeros), we get the nice result:

> `1.00526`

However, if we use some "not so nice" sample data (containing zeros for some components of the PMF), it won't work, because of a negative infinity for  `Log[0]`.

eg. Try it out with...

```
pmfA={1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6};
pmfB={1/4,1/4,1/2,0,0,0};
```

For the purpose of computing the total, I think it would be acceptable to treat the instances as "0" but I am unsure of how to implement that.

Comment: `p Log[p]/Log[q] /. -\[Infinity] -> 0` or `DeleteCases[p Log[p]/Log[q], -\[Infinity]]` are two possible implementations.

Comment: Your definition is incorrect. The ratio `p/q` should be **inside** the logarithm. @Pickett You would also have to guard against `Indeterminate` when machine-precision numbers are used, I think. But anyway, I think the point is moot - there's only one logarithm.

Comment: You may use `EmpiricalDistribution` and simply drop the zero mass entries from it. Then you can use `Expectation` to obtain the result given by @Jens as I have demonstrated [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137991/764).

Answer (score 7):

My interpretation of the question is that, after fixing the error in the definition of the divergence, the mathematical problem that is being asked about arises when the **numerator** under the `Log` goes to zero - not (as is written in the question) the **denominator**. Here is how you can then get the correct result in this case:

```
pmfA = {1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6};
pmfB = {1/4, 1/4, 1/2, 0, 0, 0};

Function[{p, q}, 
  Limit[p*Log[(p + ϵ)/(q + ϵ)], ϵ -> 
    0]][pmfB, pmfA]
Total[%]

(* ==> {1/4 Log[3/2], 1/4 Log[3/2], Log[3]/2, 0, 0, 0} *)

(* ==> 1/2 Log[3/2] + Log[3]/2 *)
```

So I switched the roles of `pmfB, pmfA` to get to the mathematically tractable case where the logarithm goes to negative infinity while being multiplied by `0`. This is calculated by introducing a formal `Limit`.