# How to implement Kullback-Leibler divergence using Mathematica's probability and distribution functions?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Last year Jens answered [a question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104506/implementation-of-kullback-leibler-divergence-in-mathematica-dealing-with-negat) about how to implement Kullback-Leibler divergence in the discrete case. He gave this answer:

```
pmfA = {1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6};
pmfB = {1/4, 1/4, 1/2, 0, 0, 0};

Function[
  {p, q}, 
  Limit[p*Log[(p + ϵ)/(q + ϵ)], ϵ -> 0]][pmfB, pmfA]
Total[%]
```

However, I was curious as to if there was a way to do this with continuous distributions using Mathematica's built-in probability related functions.

```
P = NormalDistribution[];
Q = GumbelDistribution[];

Integrate[
 Probability[x, x \[Distributed] P] Log[
   Probability[x, x \[Distributed] P]/
    Probability[x, x \[Distributed] Q]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

But this doesn't yield anything usable...

Similarly

```
\[Integral]P Log[P/Q]
```

doesn't do much either...

I have always had a hard time using *Mathematica*'s `Probability` so I would appreciate your clarification.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the continuous case the [**Kullback-Leibler-Divergence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) from distribution $Q$ to distribution $P$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
  D_{KL}( P ||Q) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p(x)\cdot \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} dx
\end{equation}

So what you need is the *probability density function* which is [`PDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) in *Mathematica*:

```
distP = NormalDistribution[]; (* avoid capital letters *)
distQ = GumbelDistribution[];

klDivergenceContinuous = Function[ { dist1, dist2 },
    NIntegrate[
        PDF[ dist1, x ] × ( Log @ PDF[ dist1, x ] - Log @ PDF[ dist2, x ] ),
        { x, -∞, +\[Infinity] }
    ]
];

klDivergenceContinuous[ distP, distQ ]
```

> 0.229783

### Update: More general solution

The definition of the expected value in the continuous case is given as

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[ f(X) ] = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\cdot p(x) dx 
\end{equation}

We can use this definition to find the KL-Divergence. Since Mathematica's implementation of [`Expectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html) will handle discrete distributions also (effectivly summing over all values instead of integrating over them), the following routine might turn out to be more general:

```
Options[ klDivergence ] = Options @ Expectation;

klDivergence[ distP_ , distQ_, opts:OptionsPattern[ klDivergence ] ] := Expectation[ 
    Log @ PDF[ distP, \[FormalX] ] - Log @ PDF[ distQ, \[FormalX] ], 
    \[FormalX] \[Distributed] distP,
    opts
]

klDivergence[ 1, distP_, distQ_, opts:OptionsPattern[ klDivergence ] ] := klDivergence[
    distP, 
    distQ, 
    opts 
]

klDivergence[ n_Integer, distP_, distQ_, opts:OptionsPattern[ klDivergence ] ] 
    /; n > 0 := Module[
    {
        vars = Table[ Unique[ \[FormalX] ], n ]
    },
    Expectation[ 
        Log @ PDF[ distP, vars ] - Log @ PDF[ distQ, vars ], 
        vars \[Distributed] distP,
        opts
    ]  
]
```

This might (in principle) work for *discrete* as well as for *continuous* distributions:

**Continuous Distributions (OP)**

```
klDivergence[ distP, distQ ]
```

> $-\frac{1}{2}+ \sqrt{\mathrm{e}} - \frac{1}{2} \log 2\pi $

```
N[%]
```

> 0.229783

**Discrete Distributions**

We may use the example given in [(104506)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104506/764) to check how this works out in the discrete case:

```
pmfA = EmpiricalDistribution[ {1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6} -> Range[6] ];
pmfB = EmpiricalDistribution[ {1/4, 1/4, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8} -> Range[6] ];

klDivergence[ pmfA, pmfB ]
```

> 1/3 (Log[4] - 3 Log[6] + 2 Log[8])

The problems arising from a discrete distribution containing zero probabilities (cf. the question linked above) may be solved by dropping the zero-entries from the distribution:

```
(* pmfB = {1/4, 1/4, 1/2, 0, 0, 0} *)
pmfBzero = EmpiricalDistribution[ {1/4, 1/4, 1/2} -> Range[3] ];

klDivergence[ pmfBzero, pmfA ]
```

> Log[ 3/Sqrt[2] ]

Comment: thank you for this. I do have a few questions though. Stylistically, why do you use `Function[{args},code]` verse `function[args_]:=`? Also what is the internal difference between `NormalDistribution[]` and `PDF[NormalDistribution[]]`? Why wouldn't functions just work on the `NormalDistribution[]`? What is the difference from `PDF[dist]` and `Probability[x, x ~ dist]`?

Comment: It is clear why the discrete case works (as in my original post), but does `PDF` work for discrete distributions / or should one use `ProbabilityDistribution`?

Comment: @SumNeuron You do need to understand the difference between a (continuous) *probability distribution*, its *density function*, a *probability* (which makes use of the density) and an *expectation*. Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) maybe. All of this is concisely implemented in Mathematica.

Comment: Just a small suggestion: I'd localize the variable `x` with `Module[{x},...` (+1).

Comment: I have now expanded the solution to include the multivariate case as well. It is quite simple to extend this further by copying the definitions to have another function `nklDivergence` which will use `NExpectation` instead of `Expectation`.

Answer (score 9):

I know that this question already has a very good answer, but I still wanted to present the [Wolfram Function Repository function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/KullbackLeiblerDivergence) I wrote specifically for this purpose (before I even found this question).

Like the solution by gwr, it uses `(N)Expectation` to compute the result, though I use `LogLikelihood` instead of `Log @ PDF[...]`. The function also checks the domains of the distributions for you.

**edit**
The current version will complain if you use an `EmpiricalDistribution`, but I submitted a new version that fixes that problem.